# Do i even want to know what you were looking at?

Tags: grammar

Do I even want to know what you were looking at?

What is this means?
Do we have any alternative way to saying in the same way?

Answer (score 4):

This is a *rhetorical question*. That means it is a question to which we do not expect an answer, because we assume that the answer is very clear to start with.

Some examples of *rhetorical questions* are:

> Can't you look where you're going?

*Literally*, we ask here if somebody is able to observe where he goes. Assuming the person is not actually blind, the *obvious answer* to the question is of course "yes". We "ask" this question when someone *did not* look where they were going. We know (assume) that they *can* but we point out that they *did not*.

> Who doesn't like a long holiday?

*Literally* we are asking someone to speak up if they don't like a long holiday. We assume that actually, *everybody* likes long holidays, so we do not expect an answer to the question. We just *ask* the question to *state* that *everybody likes a long holiday*.

Now, to get to your sentence:

> Do I even want to know what you were looking at?

The person asking this is assuming that the answer to this question is *no*.

There are a number of situations where this sentence could be used, so I will make one up.

Alice walks into a room, and she sees Bob holding a magazine in front of him. The moment she comes in, he quickly tries hides his magazine. Alice assumes that the magazine was probably not about cars, but more adult-oriented, and she says:

> Do I even want to know what you were looking at?

She does not really expect Bob to tell her *if she wants to know*. After all, how can you tell what another person wants. But the question makes it clear that she assumes the answer to be:

> No, Alice, you do not want to know what I was looking at.

Which implies this:

> No, Alice, you do not want to know that I was looking at pictures of half-dressed people.

There are several other ways to say the same thing. For instance, Alice could say what the *rhetorical question* implies:

> I don't even want to know what you were looking at!

This means basically the same, and implies that Alice means:

> I wish I had not found out that you were looking at something inappropriate.

Comment: Informative and neat. :) +1